# Kafka debezium mysql connector-based topic: For ksql streams and tables, all column values end up 'null'

Tags: mysql, connector, debezium

Debezium MySQL connector appears to be configured and working correctly, yet when I construct a stream or table in KSQL based on a topic, all column values are returned as null.

I know the connector is basically working because...

```
$ confluent consume dbbi.bi.clients --value-format avro --from-beginning
```

... delivers a lovely list of clients in the console (not shown here - but it's correctly formatted json with the expected values).
Next, I try to create a table (or a stream - doesn't matter) in ksql:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_clients (id, appname STRING) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='dbbi.bi.clients', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO', KEY='id');
```

The result:

```
ksql> select * from tbl_clients;
1563267463214 | [f | null | null
1563267463214 | [h | null | null
1563267463214 | [j | null | null
1563267463214 | [l | null | null
1563267463214 | [n | null | null
1563267463214 | [p | null | null
1563267463214 | [r | null | null
1563267463214 | [t | null | null
1563267463214 | [v | null | null
1563267463214 | [x | null | null
1563267463214 | [z | null | null
1563267463214 | [| | null | null
1563267463214 | [~ | null | null
1563286302233 | [� | null | null
```

It doesn't matter which fields are selected for the table (or stream). It doesn't matter which table (topic) is used. The value of all columns is always null. Needless to say, the values in the DB are *not* null.

One last detail: This is all under Confluent 5.2.2 and Debezium mysql connector 0.9.4.

Any ideas for the newbie? Failing that, some hints on how to debug?

Comment: Typo above:
CREATE TABLE tbl_clients (id BIGINT, appname STRING) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='dbbi.bi.clients', VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO', KEY='id');

Answer (score 0):

don't forget that Debezium sends a complex message containing before/after values and source information - see https://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mysql/#change-events-value

To convert it to a format consumable by ksql you need to extraxt the after value - see https://debezium.io/docs/configuration/event-flattening/

And older description (albeit for JSON) can be found at Debezium blog - https://debezium.io/blog/2018/05/24/querying-debezium-change-data-eEvents-with-ksql/